# Does Entity Framework Include needs the .First()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

When setting up eager loading at context creation time, many examples of using `Include` in EF appear like this (given two related entities called Resources and Variations):

```
var context = new MyContext();
context.Resources.Include(x => x.Variations).First();
return context;
```

But others don't:

`context.Resources.Include(x => x.Variations);`

Only the former appears to work for me, but I can't find any explanation as to why it's needed?

Comment: what entities do you need in your result?

Comment: Updated to mention eager loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
context.Resources.Include(x => x.Variations);
```

constructs a query that, when executed, loads all resources and their variations. You then discard that query. Never executing a query means you don't get the results of the query, and you don't get the side effects of executing that query.

You can either do something with the resources:

```
foreach (var resource in context.Resources.Include(x => x.Variations))
{
    /* ... */
}
```

or, if you only want to have the objects appear in your context,

```
using System.Data.Entity;

context.Resources.Include(x => x.Variations).Load();
```

There is, as far as I know, no way of setting up a context so that the effect of `.Include` is always implicitly performed when constructing a query. You need to include it in each query.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
context.Resources.Include(x => x.Variations);
```

you get a list of Resource object. using `.First()` will give you the first Resource in that list of Resources.

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** it is called the effect of different entity **loading's**. In the Entity Framework, there are three ladings: lazy, explicit and eagerly loading approaches that you may choose from, and use the correspondingly in the code.

In another words, Entity Framework supports three ways to load related entities:

- eager loading
- lazy loading
- explicit loading

Both three techniques shown above are discussed in detail in this article - [**Loading Related Entities**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).

Your code fragment below is using eagerly loading:

```
context.Resources.Include(x => x.Variations).First();
```

> Only the former appears to work for me, but I can't find any explanation as to why it's needed?

The later code fragment (the one without `.First()`) does not work for you, because Loading of related entities can be achieved using **eager loading** (see Eagerly loading related entities above) or the **Load method**:

```
context.Resources.Include(x => x.Variations).Load();
// or a sample like
// Load the posts related to a given blog
context.Entry(blog).Collection(p => p.Posts).Load();
```

**Edit:** If for some reason you get confused with lazy loading, then you may use the option to **switch it off in the context**.

```
public MyContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: No, that is not what lazy loading refers to. Lazy loading refers to `Variations` getting loaded by accessing the property, as in `var resource = context.Resources.Single(); /* or whatever */ foreach (var variation in resource.Variations) { }` The question definitely uses eager loading.

Comment: @hvd, i have made modifications in my answer, as the question body has changed from the time when i first posted my answer. Thus, the code example in my answer is referring to eagerly loading.

Comment: I've removed my downvote as your answer is no longer incorrect, but IMO it still does not answer the question. The code fragment that does not work *also* attempts to use eager loading.

Comment: @hvd, i have completed the answer which should address the question.

Comment: I don't think we're suggesting it for the same reason, but agreed with your conclusion (the `.Include(...).Load()` bit). That's also the one I had put in my answer, see there for my explanation. :)

Comment: i agree with your explanations, and that is why u do deserve an up-vote :)